# Keyboard input doubles each keystroke

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard

I've been working on making a dozenal calculator, so far it's going well.  I have a UI that allows me to click numerals in, but something strange happens when I use my numpad to input my numbers.

When I press any number on my numpad instead of clicking, I get doubles.
example:

If I click 2 on screen, I get "2"

If I press 2 on my numpad, I get "22"

Here's part of my UI code:

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(113, 186, 47, 30), numeral[2])) 
            AppendNumber(numeral[2]);
```

Here's part of my keyboard code:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("[2]"))
        AppendNumber(numeral[2]);
```

Here's my append code:

```
void AppendNumber (string num)
{
    if (opIsActive == false)
    {
        slotA = num;
        } else {
        slotB = num;
    }

    if (currentNumber != numeral[0])
    {
        currentNumber = currentNumber + num;
        if (opIsActive == false)
        {
            slotA = currentNumber;
            } else {
                slotB = currentNumber;
            }
        } else {
            currentNumber = num;
    }
}
```

Any ways, for now my keyboard function is disabled.  If anyone knows what the problem may be, I'd love to see.

Comment: You don't show us the events. Maybe adding e.handled = true or some flushing the keyboard buffer will help?

Comment: Can you show me an example?  Would I write:



`if(Input.GetKeyDown("[2]"))
        AppendNumber(numeral[2]);`
`if (Event.current.Equals(Event.KeyboardEvent("[2]")))
        Debug.Log("true");`

oh jeez, this comment is messy.

Comment: Sorry, no. It was just a __wild guess__ as this sounds like a likely reason. I don't do Unity :-(  In a winforms `KeyPress` event I would write `e.Handled = true;` if I had processed the key myself.  - Comments are meant to be messy, so people don't write too many of them ;-)

Comment: When I do that test, it says, "true" once for every time I type "2".  So my input is going through once I think.

Comment: I don't think I can help. Two things I noticed: There is a `Input.ResetInputAxes()` function, which I guess would reset the Input completely. And `GetKeyDown` is discouraged as it will not let the user reassign the keys.. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I usually use Input.GetAxis.  But I figured instead of going into the input manager and filling out forms, I'd just grab a key with GetKeyDown.  Now that I think of it, ResetInputAxes() sounds like a really smart idea!  I'll check it out.

Comment: You solved it, thank you sir.  It now works perfectly fine now that I'm using `GetAxis` instead of `GetKeyDown`.  Lesson learned.

Comment: Please, don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. It is generally a good idea to read the tag's description before using it.

Comment: Did you try using `GetButtonDown` for this? Because `GetAxis` is intended for other things completely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetAxis` instead of `GetKeyDown` as pointed out by TaW.  For some reason `GetKeyDown` provided double characters, eg. "22" instead of "2".

Comment: One more note on [GetKeyDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) : _You need to call this function from the Update function, since the state gets reset each frame_ not sure if that's how you did it..